# Big M method in Linear Programming - can one detect empty plan sets using the table?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have such problem with constraints on parameters (this is part of more general exercise without the constraints): $18+\mu_1\geq 0$, $6+\mu_2\geq 0$, $12+\mu_3< 0$

$$\begin{array}{c}
 f=3x_{1}+x_{2}\rightarrow\max\\
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
3x_{1}+2x_{2}\leq18+\mu_1\\
-3x_{1}+x_{2}\leq6+\mu_2\\
-4x_{1}+3x_{2}\geq-12-\mu_3\\
x_{1}\geq 0\\
x_{2}\geq 0\end{array}\right. \end{array}$$

The corresponding table is such:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|cccccc|c}
T^{0} & f & x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} & x_{4} & x_{5} & A_{1} & b\\\\
\hline x_{3} & 0 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 18+\mu_{1}\\\\
x_{4} & 0 & -3 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 6+\mu_{2}\\\\
A_{1} & 0 & -4 & 3 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -12-\mu_{3}\\\\
\hline f & 1 & 4M-3 & -3M-1 & 0 & 0 & M & 0 & -
\end{array}$$

That means I have to choose the second column (that corresponds to variable $x_2$). Now there are three possible cases to look at. I choose the case with $\frac{18+\mu_1}{2}<\frac{6+\mu_2}{1}$ and $\frac{18+\mu_1}{2}<\frac{-12-\mu_3}{3}$, which means I have to choose the first row (that corresponds to variable $x_3$). The resulting table is such:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|cccccc|c}
T^{1} & f & x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} & x_{4} & x_{5} & A_{1} & b\\\\
\hline x_{2} & 0 & \frac{3}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9+\frac{1}{2}\mu_{1}\\\\
x_{4} & 0 & -\frac{9}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 & -3-\frac{1}{2}\mu_{1}+\mu_{2}\\\\
A_{1} & 0 & -\frac{17}{2} & 0 & -\frac{3}{2} & 0 & -1 & 1 & -39-\frac{3}{2}\mu_{1}+\mu_{3}\\\\
\hline f & 1 & \frac{17}{2}M-\frac{3}{2} & 0 & \frac{3}{2}M+\frac{1}{2} & 0 & M & 0 & -
\end{array}$$

The process has ended with the weird results (with lots of M in the row that corresponds to the function $f$). Can I use that to prove that corresponding Linear Programming problem has empty plan set? (I managed to prove that the set is empty by different means and now I'm curious.)